# Access target from a instantiated component

Tags: svelte

I have an App component that I instantiate with

```
const app = new App({
    target: document.querySelector('#app')
});
```

I haven't found a way to reach the target node from the App component in the oncreate hook :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        oncreate() {
          console.log(/*target*/);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [proposal](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/550) to pass the `options` object through to `oncreate` as an argument, so you'd be able to do this:

```js
export default {
  oncreate ( options ) {
    console.log( options.target );
  }
};
```

In the meantime though, you could do it with refs:

```html
<div ref:myRef>...</div>

<script>
  export default {
    oncreate () {
      var target = this.refs.myRef.parentNode;
      console.log( target );
    }
  };
</script>
```